# Trying to delete a node in a linked list at position 'n' but an error has occured

Tags: java, recursion, runtime-error, stack-overflow

This should give an output --> 531
Since the second node has to be deleted.
Error shown is:

```
543
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "next" because "temp" is null
        at DSA.Node.delete(Node.java:81)
        at DSA.Node.main(Node.java:15)
```

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int data)
    {
        this.data=data;
        next=null;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node obj=new Node(5);
        delete(obj,2);
       
    }
public static void delete(Node head,int n)
    {
        Node temp=head;
        Node ob1=new Node(4);
        head.next=ob1;
        Node ob2=new Node(3);
        ob1.next=ob2;
        Node ob3=new Node(1);
        ob3.next=null;
        
        int i ;
        //printing original linked list
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            System.out.print(temp.data);
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        
        //deleting
        for( i=1;i<n-1;i++)
        {

            temp=temp.next;
        }
        temp.next=temp.next.next;
        // printing new linked list
        
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        

    }
```

Comment: You've tagged this with `recursion` and `stack-overflow`, but there seems to be neither of these issues in this code.

Comment: Why are you initializing 3 stubbed nodes in your delete function?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a couple of things first:

- It would be good to format your code.
- It's generally a good idea to limit the code in your method to what its name suggests it should do. This is a broad guideline with exceptions of course, but here your `delete` method clearly adds nodes to your list.

Your problem here is as follows:

```java
while (temp!=null) {
    System.out.print(temp.data);
    temp=temp.next;
}
// At this stage, "temp" is null.
        
for (i=1;i<n-1;i++) {
    // Side-node: this loop body will never run when called with n=2.
    temp=temp.next;
}

// Since "temp" is still null, using "temp.next"
// will throw a null pointer exception.
temp.next=temp.next.next;
```

To fix this you could:

- add your Nodes 4, 3 and 1 *outside* the delete loop;

  - firstly, simply because it makes more sense;
  - secondly, because you'd start afresh at your "delete" loop with `Node temp=head;`
- you'd still need to check whether `temp` or `temp.next` are `null` before trying to use `temp.next.next`. You'd also need to test whether `temp` in your `(i=1;i<n-1;i++)` loop (you could reach the end of the list before reaching `n`).

Depending on what you want your last `while` loop to do, it may have the same problems: it starts off with `temp` as it was left by the previous code. If you want it to print your new linked list, you'll need to reset `temp` to be `head`.

Answer (score 0):

The *if-conditional* within *delete* is never met.

Where, *n* is *2*, *− 1* is *1*.  Thus, *1 < 1*, is false.

```java
for( i=1;i<n-1;i++)
```

So, on the following line, *temp* is *null*.

```java
temp.next=temp.next.next;
```

If you're using an *IDE*, they typically provide a *[debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging)* console.
If not, you can use the *jdb* command tool—*[Oracle – The jdb Command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/specs/man/jdb.html)*.